# Does awk store an output file in RAM?

Tags: memory, awk

I was doing a simple parsing like `awk '{print $3 > "file1.txt"}'`

What I noticed was that awk is taking up too much of RAM (the files were huge). Does streaming awk output to file consume memory? Does this work like stream write or does the file remain open till the program terminates?

The exact command that I gave was:

```
for i in ../../*.txt; do j=${i#*/}; mawk -v f=${j%.txt} '{if(NR%8<=4 && NR%8!=0){print >f"_1.txt" } else{print >f"_2.txt"}}' $i & done
```

As evident I used mawk. The five input files were around 6GB each and when I ran `top` I saw 22% memory ~5GB being taken up by each mawk process at its peak. I noticed it because my system was hanging because of low memory.

I am particularly sure that redirection outside awk consumes negligible memory. Have done it several times with files much larger than this and operations more complex than this; I never faced this problem. Since I had to copy different sections of the input files to different output files, I used redirection inside awk.

I know there are other ways to implement this task and in any case my job is done without much issues. All I was interested in is how awk works when writing to a file.

I am not sure if this question is better suited for Superuser.

Comment: Essentially every program uses memory. What is too much? How large is the file?

Comment: You should probably say which implementation of awk you are using. (original awk, GNU awk, nawk, something else)

Comment: Try doing the redirection to your output file outside of awk.

Comment: yes, you need to include more details about your evidence. Does using `awk '{print $3}' file > file1.txt` make any difference? (I would be surprised if it did). Good luck.

Comment: I mean `awk '{print $3}' inputfile > outputfile`

Comment: I doubt very much that awk is directly managing this, much more likely that stdio.h is buffering. (I ran whatever awk I have on a 50,000,000 line file and memory hardly showed up on top.)

Comment: The stdio buffer is only a few kilobytes, though. Much too small to notice.

Comment: I'm not so sure about "primarily opinion-based", but it's off-topic because it's not about coding. It belongs at [su].

Comment: Maybe the files don't contain a single line break (some systems use "\r" others "\r\n" however most of them use "\n" as a line terminator). Make sure the terminator those files have, is the same as the one used in the system. That's the only reason I think that could make your mawk eat that much RAM...